# PHP CURL - Apple push notification servers

Tags: php, laravel, http-headers, php-curl

I am writing code to send notifications to the Apple push notification servers (APNs) using PHP Laravel. It says in the documents that it requires HTTP/ HPACK header compression.

I've tried using cURL

```
            $cURLConnection = curl_init();
            if(strcmp(env('APP_ENV'), 'production') == 0) {
                curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_URL, 'api.push.apple.com:443');
            } else {
                curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_URL, 'api.development.push.apple.com:443');
            }
            curl_setopt_array($cURLConnection, [
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER =>true,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION   =>CURL_HTTP_VERSION_2_0,
            ]);

            curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                'path: /3/device/<devicetoken>',
                'authorization: bearer ' . $token,
                'Content-Type: application/json'
            ));
            curl_setopt($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postRequest);
            curl_setopt ($cURLConnection, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
            $apiResponse = curl_exec($cURLConnection);
```

but the APNS server always returning 'Empty reply from server'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see a few things that could be problematic.

Try adding the following to actually turn your request into a POST request.

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
```

Your 'path' should also be part of the main URL instead of being added as a header.

```
curl_setopt($c, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.push.apple.com:443/3/device/<devicetoken>");
```

Comment: thank you. it is good to go now. so the HPACK actually taken care by cURL?

Comment: To be honest, I actually have no idea about HPACK, so I am glad it worked :D I just noticed you were using URL wrong.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the previous suggestion, we should also be able to use ***certificate bases*** [auth system](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/establishing_a_certificate-based_connection_to_apns).

Example snippet below:

```
<?php
  
    $ch = curl_init();
  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://path-to-auth-example.com/token');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "grant_type=client_cert");
  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, "path/to/your/pem-file.pem");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERTTYPE, "PEM");
  
    $headers = [];
    $headers[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
  
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        //catch your error wisely
    }
    curl_close($ch);
  
    $result = json_decode($result);
      
    print_r($result);
  
?>
```